# Do we have an everyday word to express the state of our mouth before crying, for example, "he twisted his mouth as if he almost cried"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When a child is about to cry or he almost cries, his mouth is twisted.

Do we have an everyday common word to express the state of our mouth before crying, for example, "**he twisted his mouth as if he almost cried**"?

Comment: **Puckered** or **crumpled**?

Comment: On EL&U [What do you call the facial expression or the state just before bursting into tears?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300672)

Comment: Also "he screwed up his face before bursting into tears".

Comment: @WeatherVane, maybe, "he screwed up his mouth before bursting into tears" sounds better?

Comment: I know the expression as I wrote it: his [face](https://cdn.xl.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/the-young-man-screwed-up-both-eyes-the-young-man-with-long-red-hair-screwed-up-both-eyes-stock-image_csp38213763.jpg).

Comment: @Wistful, I seldom see these 2 words. What about "tremble", is it more common than "Puckered or crumpled'?

Comment: More usually "his **lip** trembled".